# How can I add constraints to 4 labels in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, storyboard, uilabel

Hi I am working on an Universal App, I have a Header Cell and Prototype Cell with 4 Labels each. For the Header Cell I was able to add the constraints since the 4 Labels have equal widths, but for the Prototype Cell the last label has a smaller width and a disclosure Indicator next to it. I would like to show the labels as  they are seen in my Storyboard. How can I add constraints to show my labels the same way in every device? 
Here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: do you want 4 label equal height and width in same direction @neney

Comment: I have 8 UILabels in total, 4 in each cell. I would like to add constraints so they look exactly how they are in my storyboard in every device as shown in the screenshot

Comment: Do you want to add constraints in storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: i have answered please check it then let me know it working on your side@neney

Comment: I want to add constraints to my 2nd cell in storyboard @RajeshkumarR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are applying on `first label' top,leading,equalwidth to cell , then use`multipliyer`on equalwidth 0.25  then on second`label`Horizontal spacing ,equal height,width,center vertically from`label` first . Same on below labels but vertical spacing from upper lable then same on other label above mention. If you want to space between labels then put value in horizontal spacing.

[image]

double click on equal width then open this kind of window

[image]

put multiplier in 0.25

then it see like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it possible if you provide some screenshots on how to use multiplier please? I think whats causing the issue on my 2nd cell is the disclosure indicator next to my last label

Comment: yup wait a second@neney

Comment: Thanks just got it, the only problem is that in my second cell, my last label on the right has a different width and its next to the disclosure indicator, so  how can I add the the constraint to that last label since its in the trailing side but different width?

Comment: i didn't get your last comment@neney

Comment: if you see my screenshot the label that says $125 has a different width so I can't add Equal Width, so how can I add the constraint to that label?

Comment: do you want to flexible as content size @neney

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!, i found the solution thanks to your answer. I just had to add a center constraint to my last label with the 3rd, the height, and the trailing space without the width. Unfortunately I cant vote yet because I am new to the site. But you fixed my problem :)